# Search and comment all matches

Tags: python, pycharm

Is there a way to comment all the matches when doing CTRL+F or CTRL+R?

I have tried a quick fix, but this is not working properly when the line to be printed is in different lines:

[image]

```
# print("Hello"
        "World")
```

I am using Python 3.7 and PyCharm 2021.3.1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yeah, that a PyCharm (or any Jetbrains IDE) feature.
after search, click on the `Select All Occurrences` button (the 4th button from the right of the `33/33` in the picture you uploaded) - it will mark all occurrences of your search.
than simply comment it with Cmd+slash (or Control+slash for windows) and all the occurrences will be commented out

for the case of multi line you can use the `regex` search to match your search term something like: `^print\(.*(\n*[^\)]*)*\)$`

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want select the print function and comment the all of the print function with "Hello World" part.
You can do step by step;

1. Click CTRL+F and after then click regex button
2. Write what you want with regex( In this question you should write **`^print\(.*(\n*.*)*\)$`**). When you do that, you already select the whole line
3. If you want to make comment all of the print function you can click Select All Occurences.
4. Then you can make comment with your multiline comment shortcute